# How select some of property of a Class by custom attribute

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes, custom-attributes

I have a class by 3 property.

```
class Issuance
{
    [MyAttr]
    virtual public long Code1 { get; set; }

    [MyAttr]
    virtual public long Code2 { get; set; }

    virtual public long Code3 { get; set; }
}
```

I need to select some of properties in this class by my custom attribute(`[MyAttr]`).

I use of `GetProperties()` But this return all properties.

```
var myList = new Issuance().GetType().GetProperties();
//Count of result is 3 (Code1,Code2,Code3) But count of expected is 2(Code1,Code2)
```

How can I do it?

Comment: You need to use GetCustomAttributes on each property and check to see if any of the attributes returned are of the MyAttr type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use LINQ and a `Where` clause using [`MemberInfo.IsDefined`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.isdefined.aspx):

```
var myList = typeof(Issuance).GetProperties()
                             .Where(p => p.IsDefined(typeof(MyAttr), false);
```

Comment: That's pretty awesome Jon, I don't think I've ever used IsDefined before - is this just a wrapper around GetCustomAttributes?

Comment: @Charleh: I don't know - but it's certainly simpler to use :)

Comment: My problem is resolved. Of course  this sample code needed to a `ToList()` in end of LINQ.

Comment: @Ehsan: It only needs `ToList` if you need a list :) If you're just iterating over the properties, there's no need for a `ToList` call.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getcustomattributes.aspx

Try this - basically do a foreach on the properties and see if you get back your attribute type for each property. If you do, that property has the attribute:

e.g.

```
foreach(var propInfo in new Issuance().GetType().GetProperties()) 
{
    var attrs = propInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyAttr), true/false); // Check docs for last param

    if(attrs.Count > 0)
      // this is one, do something
}
```